# Generators - thunkifying JSON.parse returns odd results

Tags: json, node.js, generator, ecmascript-harmony, co

I am trying to read a JSON file using co and generators. `test.json` contains:

```
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```

This passes `jsonlint` so it should be valid. Here is my code at present:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony
var co = require('co'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  thunkify = require('thunkify');

var read = thunkify(fs.readFile);
var JSONParse = thunkify(JSON.parse);

var log = console.log.bind(console);

co(function *(){
  var fileContents = yield read('test.json', 'utf-8');
  var works = yield JSONParse(fileContents)
  log(works)
})()
```

Only an empty object is logged. However `fileContents` is full, so it seems to be the JSON.parse part that's broken. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Silly me, [JSON.parse is sync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). So no need to wrap.

```
var fileContents = yield read('public/data/works.json', 'utf-8');
log(JSON.parse(fileContents))
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, when does thunkify call your co function?